# Why action link isn't responding?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to add this action link but it isn't working, it's giving me an error of path cant be found
here's the code:

```
public class CenterController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

and in the HTML I've tried two ways but both didn't work

```
 // <li><a href="\Users\Center">Center Page</a></li>
 <li>@Html.ActionLink("Center", "Index", "Users")</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have the controller and action wrong way round - For the **Index** action on the **Center** controller you should do:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Index", "Center")</li>
```

So with the text it is:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Users", "Index", "Center")</li>
```

Assuming you want the link to say "Users"

Comment: Thanks, so when I want to call a different ActionResult in the same page I need to do <li>@Html.ActionLink("Users", "Example", "Center")</li> ?

Comment: @User89 - I don't understand your question... You always specify ActionLink("TextToDisplay", "ActionName", "ControllerName") to generate links - as per the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

Comment: I meant that when I need to call a different action in the same controller do I need to implement the given answer with a different action ?

Comment: @User89 - still not understanding, what do you mean 'implement the given answer'?

Comment: You would just change the second parameter (marked "ActionName" in my comment) to the name you called the action...

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was referring too